# Let u be a real $n \times 1 $ vector satisying $u^T u = 1$ and $A = I - 2uu^T$ Then which of the following is (are) true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let u be a real $n \times 1 $ vector satisying $u^T u = 1$ and $A = I - 2uu^T$ Then which of the following is (are) true?

a) A is singular

b) $A^2 = A$

c) Trace(A) = n-2

d) $A^2 = I$

I have tried in the following way

$uu^T$ is rank 1 matrix.  Columns of this matrix contains one linearly independent vector with different magnitude. If subtract it from I (identity Matrix) which gives A. Suppose $uu^T=[a_1u ~~ a_2u~~ ...a_nu]$ where $a_i$ are real constants, of course $a_i$'s are elements of u.

How can I check the options in question using A?

Answer (score 4):

It is immediate that $A^2=I$, which you can verify by 
$$
(I-2uu^T)^2=I+4uu^Tuu^T-4uu^T=I+4uu^T-4uu^T=I.
$$
Let me explain how I saw this: by diagonalizing, I can see $I-2uu^T$ as $I-2E_{11}$, i.e. there exists a unitary $V$ such that 
$$\tag{1}
V^*(I-2uu^T)V=\begin{bmatrix}-1&0&\cdots&0\\ 0&1&\cdots&0\\
0&0&\ddots&0\\ 0&0&\cdots&1,
\end{bmatrix}
$$
from where we immediately see that it is its own inverse. So now from $(1)$ we know that $A$ is invertible, that $A^2=I$, and that $\text{Tr}(A)=n-2$. This last one can be done directly:
$$
\text{Tr}(I-2uu^T)=\text{Tr}(I)-2\text{Tr}(uu^T)=n-2\times1=n-2.
$$

Answer (score 2):

Observe that
$$
A^2=AA=(I-2uu')(I-2uu')=I-4uu'+4uu'uu'=I-4uu'+4u(u'u)u'=I
$$
where the last equality is because $u'u=1$. Thus (d) is true and (b) is false. (a) is also false because $A^2=I$ implies $\det(A)=\pm 1$, i.e., not $0$. For (c), note that
$$
\text{tr}(A)=\text{tr}(I)-2\text{tr}(uu')=\text{tr}(I)-2\text{tr}(u'u)=n-2.
$$
So (c) is also true.